# Displaying the output of a calculation process

Tags: c#, return, output, multiplication

Sorry if this may be not explained in the best manner, but what I basically want to do is display the output of the calculation that I have created. The calculation is ancient egyptian multiplication (I was given a story to create a program where a user has the choice to calculate values using this method and note that we were not aloud to use the * and / operators) and I want to be able to show the powers that are being used, the values being calculated and the overall result. I want to return all of these outputs into a pop up box if possible but I'm not sure about how I will go about it seeing as I'm new to C# (Apprentice).

Here is an example of how I want the output

```
Powers: 1 + 4 + 8 = 13
Values: (1 * 238) + (4 * 238) + (8 * 238)
Result: 238 + 952 + 1904 = 3094
```

Here is the code I have at the minute for the ancient egyption multiplication:
Note iReturnP = Power, iReturnN = Values, iReturn = Result

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleMath
{
    public class AEM : IOperation
    {
        public int Calculate(int i, int j)
        {

            int[] ints = new int[] { i, j };
            Array.Sort(ints);
            List<int> powers = new List<int>();
            int power = 1;
            int first = ints[0];
            int iReturn = 0;
            int iReturnP = 0;
            int iReturnN = 0;
            do
            {
                powers.Add(power);
                power = new Multiply().Calculate(power, 2);
            } while (power <= first);
            iReturnP += first;
            while (first > 0)

            {
                int next = powers.LastOrDefault(x => x <= first);
                first -= next;
                int powertotal = new Multiply().Calculate(next, i);

                iReturnN += next;
                iReturn += powertotal;
            }
            return iReturnP;
            return iReturnN;
            return iReturn;

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot return 3 times!!! except that what is your real problem?

Comment: That IS his problem...

Comment: @makc beginner programmer, cut some slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you run a `return` statement the method will be exited. This means your 2nd and 3rd `return` statement will never happen. If you really want to use the `return` statement I suggest you return an `int[]` containing all 3 values. There are a bunch of other ways to go about this too. Note that this will only provide you with the totals. I'll get you on your way, but you'll have to do some work yourself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleMath
{
public class AEM : IOperation
{
    public static int[] Calculate(int i, int j)
    {

        int[] ints = new int[] { i, j };
        Array.Sort(ints);
        List<int> powers = new List<int>();
        int power = 1;
        int first = ints[0];
        int iReturn = 0;
        int iReturnP = 0;
        int iReturnN = 0;
        do
        {
            powers.Add(power);
            power = new Multiply().Calculate(power, 2);
        } while (power <= first);
        iReturnP += first;
        while (first > 0)

        {
            int next = powers.LastOrDefault(x => x <= first);
            first -= next;
            int powertotal = new Multiply().Calculate(next, i);

            iReturnN += next;
            iReturn += powertotal;
        }
        return new int[]{iReturnP, iReturnN, iReturn};

        }
}
}
```

And then in your method where you call calculate:

```
int[] results = AEM.Calculate(i, j);
MessageBox.Show("Powers: " + results[0] + "\r\n Values: " + results[1] + "\r\n Results: " + results[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was helpful in the way that I wont make the same mistake of trying to return more than once. Could we just display a message box then to show the outputs?

Comment: You can do anything you want with the outputs. Tell me what you want to achieve and where you want the output to arive and I'll try to help you

Comment: I know that, but do you want to display it from inside your calculate method or from within the method where you call it?

Comment: I want the program to display a messagebox when the calculate button is pressed and present the result from the calculation generated in this kind of format: Powers: 1 + 4 + 8 = 13 Values: (1 * 238) + (4 * 238) + (8 * 238) Result: 238 + 952 + 1904 = 3094. Apologies once again if it's quite hard to understand my point.

Comment: I'll provide you with an answer with a return statement. Don't use this for everything you want to code because it's far from foolproof to return an array when you want to return multiple variables

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, and yeah I understand but either way it still gives a rough idea on what to do in the future